# Titan storage.backend=inmemory Causes Incompatible Data Type Exception

Tags: testing, cassandra, titan, in-memory-database

I've been using titan-cassandra storage.backend=cassandra in my testing environment and recently learned that I can simply plop in storage.backend=inmemory to test with an in-memory graph. As this will drastically increase the speed of the hundreds of tests - this sounds great. But, making this change to my otherwise simple test configuration causes many of my once passing tests to fail. Here's my configuration:

```
storage.backend=inmemory
storage.hostname=localhost
storage.cassandra.keyspace=test
```

There are two errors that come up, the vast majority being:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompatible data types for: variable
```

while much less commonly:

```
com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not commit transaction due to exception during persistence
```

Any idea on how I can resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I do my tests using in memory graph database too. While, I don't specify anything for hostname, I tried using, now, localhost, and it still works. I believe the problem might be somewhere else and you have fixed it by now.